# iPad with iOS 8.1.1 diawi wireless installation failed

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8.1

iPad with iOS 8.1.1 diawi wireless installation failed
I can run this app to iPad from xcode. But wireless installation using diawi fails. Profiles are all correct. The same build with same link is installing on other iPad Mini. Other apps can also install on this iPad.
Any idea what the probelm is..?

Comment: What exactly does the failure say? The error message?

Comment: nothing is there. it asks whether to install the app, when I tap install , nothing happens...